# import "praw" could not be resolved

Tags: python, discord.py

How to fix : import "praw" could not be resolved

Here is my code:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="",
    client_secret="",
    user_agent="",
    username="",
    password="",
)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")

top = subreddit.top(limit = 5)

for submission in top:
       print(submission.title)
```

Comment: Have you got another file called `praw.py`?

Comment: @LukaszKwieciński nope

Comment: Don't use praw. Use Async Praw instead. It's the same except its for async environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me too. Simple solution is to use asyncpraw

```
pip install asyncpraw
```

Here is how I did it:-

```
reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(client_id = '',
                     client_secret = '',
                     username = '',
                     password = '',
                     user_agent = '')

subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("memes)

top = subreddit.top(limit=5)

for submission in top:
       print(submission.title)
```